# Select Table of Days For One Year SQLITE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite, date, recursive-query

I am trying to select a table of every date for the last year.

In SQL Server, I can run something like this:

```
SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, DATEADD(YEAR, - 1, GETDATE()), GETDATE()) + 1) 
    Date = CAST(DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1, DATEADD(YEAR, - 1, GETDATE())) AS DATE) 
FROM sys.all_objects a
```

It returns 1 column with 366 rows containing the dates from 1 year ago until now.

I am looking for something equivalent in SQLITE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a recursive CTE:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT DATE(CURRENT_DATE, '-1 year') date
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE(date, '+1 day') 
  FROM cte
  WHERE date < CURRENT_DATE
)
SELECT * FROM cte;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=ed80166f39db2f087015388821fe964c).

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this using an inline tally table

```sql
WITH L1(n) AS (
  VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
),
L2(n) AS (
  SELECT 1 FROM L1 a CROSS JOIN L1 b
)
SELECT DATE(CURRENT_DATE, (-ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 1) + 1) || ' days') AS date
FROM L2
LIMIT julianday(CURRENT_DATE) - julianday(DATE(CURRENT_DATE, '-1 year')) + 1;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=7b3f5081904eb9305f92bff4de64db04)

For newer versions of SQLite you may want to add `NOT MATERIALIZED` to the CTEs.